# Accessing a file in a database

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand how the following 2 code snippets create tables in a file and save it in a database, and how I can access the file that they create (view, edit, parse, etc). The codes belong to a few C# scripts as part of a Unity application. I think this is where I can find out **where** the file is created and saved.

When I copy&paste the url (`http://111.222.333./projec.php`) in a web browser, I get a white page that says: *test ok*.

So, this means the experiment results (tables, etc...) are definitely created in a `php` file, and such a file cannot be opened in a web browser, because it is a server-side language. **Correct?**

Quickly reading up on `php`, I realized that if I want to be able to see the contents, tables, values, etc... I should use JavaScript to *query* things and get *information*. Is that my only option to see the results? Is there an *Editor* that I can put the `url` from the code below and directly see the file structure and contents?

```
public static IEnumerator CreateDatabase( ExperimentCreator creator )
{
    Experiment experiment = creator.getExperiment();
    url = experiment.GetUrl();

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField( "action", "Create" );
    databaseName = experiment.DatabaseName;
    form.AddField( "database", databaseName );

    WWW w = new WWW( url, form );
    yield return w;

    if ( w.error != null )
    {
        creator.EditorConnectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.ConnectionFailed;
    }
    else
    {
        if( w.text == "EXISTS" )
        {
            creator.DatabaseExistsError();
        }
        else
        {
            createTables( experiment );
            creator.DatabaseSuccess();
        }
    }

    // print ( url );
    // Debug.Log (url);
}
```

=======================================================

```
public class DataBaseConnection : MonoBehaviour
{
    static string   url = "http://111.222.333./projec.php";
    static bool     on = false;
    static int      uniqueId;
    static string   databaseName;


    void Start ()
    {}


    void Update ()
    {}


    #region SENDING EXPERIMENT FEEDBACK

    public static IEnumerator SendInputResultsToDatabase( string table, string[] names, string[] inputs )
    {
        if( on )
        {
            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

            form.AddField( "database", databaseName      );
            form.AddField( "action",   "InsertIntoTable" );
            form.AddField( "table",    table             );

            string fields = "subjectID";
            string results = uniqueId.ToString();

            for( int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++ )
            {
                fields += ", " + names[i];
                results += ", " + inputs[i];
            }

            form.AddField( "fields",  fields  );
            form.AddField( "results", results );

            WWW w = new WWW( url, form );
            yield return w;
        }
    }
```

=======================================================

I would very much appreciate simple explanations to help me understand what's going on here, if I have any wrong concepts in my mind, etc...

Thank you

Comment: `http://111.222.333./projec.php` is just a url. c# app is sending data to it, just like if you fill in an html form on a website. Unless you have access to the server, you have no way of telling whats happening there.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I do have access to the server, but I cannot seem to find such a file (projec.php)

Comment: What access do you have? Where did you look for the file?

Comment: http://111.222.333 takes me to the department's project page but I cannot see to find any structure or file called projec.php

Comment: Do I have to retrieve this file somehow? How do I even ensure it's been created and exists?

Comment: By access to the server, i mean you can log into the computer that is residing at that IP addess. Typing the ip address into your browser is not the same as having access. I you dont own the server or have login details for it, then you cant go any further.